# Why I should use interface instead of directly declaring method inside of the class without interface

Tags: c#, .net, class, methods, interface

can you please explain why really i need use interface instead  of  directly declaring and implementing method inside of Class. Above i have two example. Class with interface and without.  Thanks in advance.

> **EXAMPLE1** Why i should  use this

```
interface ISampleInterface
{
    void SampleMethod();
}

class ImplementationClass : ISampleInterface
{
    // Explicit interface member implementation: 
    void ISampleInterface.SampleMethod()
    {
        // Method implementation.
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // Declare an interface instance.
        ISampleInterface obj = new ImplementationClass();

        // Call the member.
        obj.SampleMethod();
    }
}
```

> **EXAMPLE2**  why i shouldn't use this

```
class ImplementationClass
    {
        void SampleMethod()
        {
            // Method implementation.
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            // Declare an interface instance.
            ImplementationClass obj = new ImplementationClass();

            // Call the member.
            obj.SampleMethod();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's no reason why you shouldn't use the second one, what is your actual use case?

Comment: I would actually do a google search on the difference between `Class vs Interfaces` this would give you a better understanding on the `When and Why`